# error ...it doesn't recognise code ending

Tags: php

```
<?php
        $file_handle=fopen("normal.txt","rb");
        $i=0;
        while (!feof($file_handle)){
         $fline=gets($file_handle);
         $fparts=preg_split("/:|;\");

         $x_values[$i]=(float)$parts[1];
         $y_values[$i]=(float)$parts[2];
         $i=$i+1;

}

   include 'libchart/libchart/classes/libchart.php';
   $data_length=sizeof($x_values);

   for(i=0;$i< $data_length; $i++)
     $dataset -> addPoint(newPoint('',$y_values[$i]));
    $chart -> render('figs/text.png');

  ?>
//this part is not recognised...so it is thhrowing an error.
```

I think the rest of the code is ok....but that thing keeps throwing that error at the end of my code.I just don't know why...could please someone help me? I'd appreciate that much .That is the only error i find....if there are others too please tell me...i am just a beginner at website designing...
    So your help is precious to me

Comment: For the next time: If you get an error message *put it in the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have delimted your closing quote in this line:

```
preg_split("/:|;\");
```

You should put in a second `\` to counter it:

```
preg_split("/:|;\\", $string);
```

Normally when you put a `\` before a quotation, it means "treat the quotation as part of the string". As you don't want it to mean that you need to delimit the delimiter heh. The compiler thinks that the rest of your code is still part of the string - even the syntax highlight here on SO is showing it.

See the difference:

```
     $fline=gets($file_handle);
     $fparts=preg_split("/:|;\\", $string);

     $x_values[$i]=(float)$parts[1];
     $y_values[$i]=(float)$parts[2];
     $i=$i+1;
```

Edit: The elephant in the room was pointed out by KarelG. Good show. preg_split does indeed need to params. Without the extra `\` it would have still not worked though :)

Comment: just saying, the action is useless if you don't add a second parameter, which is the string to use the pattern on. For further reference: [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)-manual